# Pass String Variable to Generic <T>

Tags: c#, generics

I have the Following Method used to walk the Visual Tree to find all objects of a Type:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (depObj != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
            {
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                if (child != null && child is T)
                {
                    yield return (T)child;
                }

                foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
                {
                    yield return childOfChild;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The Problem is the Type is a string value stored in a veriable. Using the Above works fine when passed a Type like the following:

```
var x = FindVisualChildren<TextBox>(this);
```

However in my case TextBox is a string stored in a variable we will call item. So I want to do something like this:

```
var item = "TextBox";
var x = FindVisualChildren<item>(this);
```

But Item is not a type. So what is the best way to get the Type of the Sting Variable so it can be passed to my method. The Variable will be a TextBox, TextBlock, Grid, StackPanel, DockPanel, or TabControl. Right now I have everything in a Switch Statement and it is working but would like a cleaner way to do the same thing.

Comment: I believe that you have to use reflection for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method

Comment: As @syazdani said. You need to get the type from the string using [Type.GetType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx) and from that you can follow Jon Skeet's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/232621/1250301) using [MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod(v=vs.110).aspx) and then `Invoke` it.

Comment: What is the end goal? You can't _use_ the result at compile-time since the compiler does not know what the type of the collection is.  What are you going to _do_ with `x`?

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, you need to use reflection.

First you need to obtain the `Type` that you want to use.

You can do it in two ways. You can create `Type` from a string that specifies that type name like this:

```
var type_name = "System.Windows.Controls.TextBox, PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35";

var type = Type.GetType(type_name, true);
```

Or you can define the type directly like this:

```
var type = typeof (TextBox);
```

Then you need to use reflection to obtain the `MethodInfo` like this:

```
var method = typeof (StaticClass).GetMethod("FindVisualChildren", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
```

Where `StaticClass` is the name of the static class that contains the `FindVisualChildren` method.

Then you can invoke the method like this:

```
IEnumerable result = (IEnumerable)method.MakeGenericMethod(type).Invoke(null, new object[] { this});
```

Please note that I am casting to `IEnumerable` and not `IEnumerable<T>`.